# Encode uint16 png with tfrecord (depth_data)

Tags: tensorflow

In order to **encode the uint16 png with tfrecord**, I implemented the following codes. However, it outputs "uint8", how to modify it? Thank you~

```
def _bytes_list_feature(values):
"""Returns a TF-Feature of bytes.

Args:
values: A string.

Returns:
A TF-Feature.
"""
  def norm2bytes(value):
    if isinstance(value, str) and six.PY3:
      print "endcode"
      return value.encode()
    else:
      # print value
      return value

  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[norm2bytes(values)]))


def image_to_tfexample(depth_data):
  """Converts depth to tf example.

  Args:
    depth_data: string of depth data.

  Returns:
    tf example of depth.
  """
  return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image/depth/encoded': (
      _bytes_list_feature(depth_data)),
    'image/depth/format': _bytes_list_feature(
      FLAGS.depth_format),
  }))
```

The following Decode codes are used to specify how the TF-Examples are decoded. The decoder's dtype is uint8, while the dtype of source one is uint16. **How to encode and decode uint16 image with tfrecord.**

```
keys_to_features = {
  'image/depth/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature(
      (), tf.string, default_value=''),
  'image/depth/format': tf.FixedLenFeature(
      (), tf.string, default_value='png'),
}
items_to_handlers = {
  'depth': tfexample_decoder.Image(
      image_key='image/depth/encoded',
      format_key='image/depth/format',
      channels=1),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tfexample_decoder.py, I make some changes as follows, and it works.

1. image_ops.decode_image(image_buffer, channels=self._channels, dtype=self._dtype)
2. replace image = control_flow_ops.case(pred_fn_pairs, default=check_jpeg, exclusive=True) with image = decode_image()

**complete code**

```
def _decode(self, image_buffer, image_format):
"""Decodes the image buffer.

Args:
  image_buffer: The tensor representing the encoded image tensor.
  image_format: The image format for the image in `image_buffer`. If image
    format is `raw`, all images are expected to be in this format, otherwise
    this op can decode a mix of `jpg` and `png` formats.

Returns:
  A tensor that represents decoded image of self._shape, or
  (?, ?, self._channels) if self._shape is not specified.
"""

def decode_image():
  """Decodes a image based on the headers."""
  return image_ops.decode_image(image_buffer, channels=self._channels, **dtype=self._dtype**)

def decode_jpeg():
  """Decodes a jpeg image with specified '_dct_method'."""
  return image_ops.decode_jpeg(
      image_buffer, channels=self._channels, dct_method=self._dct_method)

def check_jpeg():
  """Checks if an image is jpeg."""
  # For jpeg, we directly use image_ops.decode_jpeg rather than decode_image
  # in order to feed the jpeg specify parameter 'dct_method'.
  return control_flow_ops.cond(
      image_ops.is_jpeg(image_buffer),
      decode_jpeg,
      decode_image,
      name='cond_jpeg')

def decode_raw():
  """Decodes a raw image."""
  return parsing_ops.decode_raw(image_buffer, out_type=self._dtype)

pred_fn_pairs = {
    math_ops.logical_or(
        math_ops.equal(image_format, 'raw'),
        math_ops.equal(image_format, 'RAW')): decode_raw,
}

**# image = control_flow_ops.case(
#     pred_fn_pairs, default=check_jpeg, exclusive=True)

image = decode_image()**

image.set_shape([None, None, self._channels])
if self._shape is not None:
  image = array_ops.reshape(image, self._shape)

return image
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert but I had a quick look at the code. It looks like tfexample_decoder.Image only supports uint8 for now. You probably need to update TF code to achieve your goal

image.decode_image operator supports both uint8 and uint16 image, however, tfexample_decoder.Image didn't pass it in.

It might just work if you simply pass in dtype to decode_image

Refs:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/26f66133f86ed6f7371e0cbc2b9bd4f30bf16e93/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data/tfexample_decoder.py#L420
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/26f66133f86ed6f7371e0cbc2b9bd4f30bf16e93/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L1846